# How to select option with array value

Tags: php, sql

Can someone explain me how to make a select option with the value's of an array. I wrote some code myself but the field remains empty.

```
<select id="gebruiker" name="gebruiker" class="form-control">
   <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

      while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
      ?>
           <option value="<?php
              echo $row1[0]; ?>">
              <?php
                 echo "<p>$row1[0] $row1[1]</p>"; ?>
           </option>
   <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
</select>
```

The code needs to display the ID of the user ($row[0]) and the name ($row[1]).

Comment: `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;` <- remove that trailing semi-colon. Also, specify the columns you want in your `SELECT` clause, eg `SELECT something, somethingElse FROM...`

Comment: Fixed it myself already, didn't declare the $conn variable so the query didn't know where to execute it.

Comment: If this is a simple error - you can delete your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can clean up your code a little bit. There is not need to keep opening and closing php tags you can just print the HTML as part of your *echo* function by escaping double quotes with a backlash (i.e. "\"), but I would advise you to use single quotes inside a double quoted *echo*.

I would also replace your *while* with a *foreach*. Assume your variable *$result* is as you defined:

```
<select id="gebruiker" name="gebruiker" class="form-control">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $rows=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as &$row) {
        echo "
            <option value='$row[0]'>
                <p>$row[0] $row[1]</p>
            </option>
        ";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

PHP:

```
<?php
    function getSelectItems()
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
        $table = array();

        if ($result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users")) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $counter = 0;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $table[$counter] = $row;
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        $con->close();

        return $table;
    }
?>

<select id="gebruiker" name="gebruiker" class="form-control">
    <?php
        $items = getSelectItems();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++)
        {
            $row = $items[$i];
            echo "<option value=\"".$row[0]."\">".$row[0]." ".$row[1]."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

It is nice to separate the logic from the view. Therefore, I have outsourced here fetching data into a function.

This makes the view clearer.